# XML file not valid only on DigitalOcean server

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, digital-ocean

I have a problem with xml file validator. On DigitalOcean server with WordPress, xml file is not valid, but on other server file is valid.

I download a file from DO server, re-upload to another server, and file, the link is valid.

Where I need to look this problem, with DO server php configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with fail2ban plugin activate on WordPress on DO with one click standart WordPress installation.